# How can I catch a Laravel error from another Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, curl, error-handling

I have two Laravel applications and one is calling an API from the other.

If the requesting application sends invalid data, the API calls Laravel's "abort" function.

However, I can't seem to catch this error on the requesting application side. Here is some code:

Requesting application:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

if ($method == 'POST') {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));    
}

$result = curl_exec($ch);

Log::info($result);

curl_close($ch);
```

And my receiving application:

```
if ($result == '') {
    $error = 'An unexpected error occurred fetching shipping rates. If this error persists, please contact support.';
    abort(400, $error, array('errorText'=>$error));
    $error = true;
}
```

Now, I can't particularly modify my receiving application's error handling, as that application is already handling these error messages properly.

But in my requesting application, the result of the `Log::info` call is the entire HTML with the error code deeply embedded.

I can't seem to get that message without some custom string parsing, but I feel there should be some method of knowing that it failed and retrieving that error message.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch the exception, but you can add different logic for different status codes returned, in this case, 400.

```
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($statusCode == 400) {
    // Do things
}
```

How to handle this in a more generic way is really up to you and how you want your API to behave.  For example, if you want to add authorization to your API and someone passes in invalid credentials, you'd probably want to `abort(401)` which means Unauthorized.  You can see a list of status codes here and what they mean... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

If you are the only one consuming this service though, it's really up to you how in-depth you need to get here.  Generally though, anything in the 200 range means it was successful so you may just need to check that the status code is 200, otherwise you can assume there was an error.

Regarding how to get the error message out of the HTML, there really isn't a good way to do this, and you really shouldn't have to.  The better solution would be to alter your API so it doesn't return all the HTML, but instead returns responses which are more easily parsed out.  For example, if your API returns JSON, you might want to return a JSON response with the error message, status code, and any other information you might find useful, when there is an error.  To do that, you'd need to change `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` so it knows that it needs to return JSON responses rather than HTML on error.

You may also find the documentation for modifying error responses helpful, which can be found here... https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#the-exception-handler

Specifically, it looks like you will need to change the `render` method.  In the case of returning it as JSON, it might need to look something like this...

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    return response()->json([
        'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        'code' => $exception->getCode(),
    ]);

    // return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

This would return just the error message and the status code.

Comment: Hmm I just tried this and logged the statusCode being returned, and for some reason it is 0, not 400.

Comment: That's strange, did you do it before you used `curl_close`?

Comment: Yes, but it was also before the `curl_exec`. Silly me. Now is there a generic way of finding out if it's an error besides comparing it to 400?

Comment: Also, how can I grab the error text message without explicitly parsing this massive string?

Comment: I've updated the answer hopefully answering your questions.